# Can I change the values of a FILE variable without saving the file?

Tags: c++

I have a txt file that I want to change all characters.

So I'm opening it with this line:

```
FILE *myFile = fopen(filename, "rb");
```

The rest of the program uses `myFile` variable after loaded.

My goal is: crypt this file with another program and decrypt when I load without messing with the rest of the code and keep the original file crypted.

Is there a way?

Comment: So you have an actual file on your computer, which is encrypted, and you wish to load the encrypted file in, decrypt it, use it somehow (read values etc) but preserve the encryption on the original file?

Comment: yes.. that is it. Actually I want to crypt a File and after Decrypt into the program. I'm wondering if I can do this without copying to another variable because the rest of the software is using "myFile" variable with "fread" to a lot of other things. So if I just crypt it, everything else will stop work properly.

Comment: Read the file into memory and decrypt it there. You won't be able to use a FILE pointer to access it though.

Comment: bad news haha 
Thanks for the help! =)